# Motivation for $dF=0$?

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, maxwell-equations

Recently I have been studying differential geometry, and in the book I’m studying Maxwell’s Equations are derived using the 2-form $$F=E\cdot dr\wedge dt+B\cdot d\sigma.$$ They then state that $$dF=0.$$ I understand $F$ is defined to yield Maxwell’s Equations, but is there additional meaning and motivation behind it, I.e., What exactly does it mean (from a physical standpoint) that the 2-form is closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your starting point.

1. If you postulate that the electromagnetic field is described by a two-form $F= \frac{1}{2} F_{\mu \nu} \, dx^\mu \, \wedge dx^\nu$ (summation convention used), the equation $dF=0$ reproduces the two homogeneous Maxwell equations ${\rm div} \, \vec{B}=0$ and ${\rm curl}\, \vec{E} + \partial\vec{B}/\partial t =0$ (I am using units where $c=1$).
2. If you postulate that the electromagnetic field is described by a $U(1)$ gauge field, your starting point is the one-form $A= A_\mu \, dx^\mu$ and the two-form $F:=  dA$ fulfills the equation $dF=0$ simply because of $dd=0$.
3. Both formulations are, of course, mathematically equivalent ($dF=0$ implies $F=dA$ under the usual topological conditions being fulfilled here). However, in order to derive Maxwell's equations (including also the inhomogeneous ones with the current one-form $j=j_\mu \, dx^\mu$) from an action principle  (action integral), the 4-vector potential $A$ is needed and approach 2 is usually  preferred in more advanced presentations of the subject.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't really any novel physical interpretation of the Faraday 2-form $F$ being closed. What it does is give (along with the equation $d*F = 0$) a differential geometric formulation of the Maxwell theory, allowing one to make connections with geometry and topology more explicit, for example you can speak of "topological invariants" arising from these solutions in a more natural and coordinate free way. This leads one to the study of solitons, and in the more general case of Yang-Mills theory, instantons, which is a very rich and beautiful subject, at the interface of differential geometry and (semi-classical) field theory. If you are interested in instantons and solitons, check out David Tong's [TASI Lectures on Solitons](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/tasi/tasi.pdf), although they might presuppose more quantum field theory than you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

One implication of $dF=0$ is that $F=dA$, i.e. there exists a 4-potential $A$, which could be regarded as more important than $\vec E$ and $\vec B$.

Update:

$dF=0$ is associated with the observed situation that there are no isolated magnetic monopoles.

Comment: $dF=0$ ($F$ is a closed form) is a weaker condition compared to $F=dA$ ($F$ is an exact form), so the logical direction is actually $F=dA \implies dF=0$, not the other way around.

Comment: @LeoL Yes, thanks. But I’m assuming the typical physics assumption of working in a simply connected space.

Answer (score 0):

In the language of differential forms Maxwell's equations read
\begin{align}
&dF=0 \\
&d{\star F}=J
\tag{M1}\label{M1}
\end{align}

There is no additional physical meaning than what is contained in the Maxwell's equations you already know. In fact, we're only using a different language to write the *same* equations.

More specifically, the first of \eqref{M1} is a consequence (see [Bianchi Identities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bianchi_identity)) of the definition of the 2-form $F$ as the exterior derivative of the electromagnetic 4-potential form
$$F:=dA\implies dF=d^2A=0\tag{F}\label{F1}$$
where in the last equality I've used the fact the exterior derivative operator composed with itself (roughly speaking) yields zero.$^1$
You might be more familiar with the component form of \eqref{F1}
$$F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu\implies\partial_\mu\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}=0\tag{M2}\label{M2}$$
where
$$\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}:=\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}F_{\rho\sigma}$$ are the (contravariant) components of the dual form ${\star F}$. If you write \eqref{M2} explicity you get

\begin{align}
&\nabla\cdot\vec{B}=0 \\
&\nabla\times\vec{E}=-\partial_t\vec{B}
\end{align}

In a similar fashion, the second of the \eqref{F1} in component form is given by
$$\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=j^{\nu}\tag{M3}\label{M3}$$ which written explicitly yields
\begin{align}
&\nabla\cdot\vec{E}=\rho \\
&\nabla\times\vec{B}=\vec{J}+\partial_t\vec{E}
\end{align}
which are the actual EoM of the fields.

---

$^1$
<sub>This is the generalization of $\nabla\times(\nabla f)=0$.</sub>